# AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

1. This is the hints,how can I resolve it?
2. I use Python 3.5.1 created a virtual envirement by virtualenv
3. The source code works well on my friend's computer machine

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    from django.utils.log import configure_logging
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\log.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError,
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.http.response import (
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q, QuerySet, Prefetch  # NOQA
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.db.models.fields import AutoField, Empty
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django import forms
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\forms\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.forms.fields import *  # NOQA
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.forms.utils import from_current_timezone, to_current_timezone
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\forms\utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from django.utils.html import format_html, format_html_join, escape
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .html_parser import HTMLParser, HTMLParseError
  File "A:\Python3.5\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    HTMLParseError = _html_parser.HTMLParseError
AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'
```

Comment: Is your friend using the same versions as you?

Comment: Searching for that error message gives quite a few results, have you actually done any research?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: My django version is 1.8.7.,I installed it by vituralenv with requirement.txt.So his virsion is the same as mine.

Answer (score 44):

As you can read [here](http://thefourtheye.in/2015/02/15/python-35-and-django-17s-htmlparseerror/) this error is raised...

> because `HTMLParseError` is deprecated from Python 3.3 onwards and removed in Python 3.5.

What you can do is downgrade your Python version or upgrade your Django version.

Comment: The "here" link is no longer available.

Comment: `pip install Django --upgrade`

Answer (score 27):

I've just got the same error here. The Django version installed on my machine was 1.7.

Upgrading to Django 1.8.* solved the problem for me.

Comment: My django version is 1.8.7.,I installed it by vituralenv with requirement.txt.

Comment: reading your traceback it doesn't look that you are running your project with virtualenv. Are you sure that it is activated?

Comment: A tutorial I was following had version 1.7.1 installed and I ran into the same issue. Your recommendation to upgrade to 1.8.8 fixed the problem I was having, thank you!

Comment: @heavyweight do not use 1.8.8 now since many updates were made in 1.8 series including security patches. The last version today is 1.8.13 ;)

Answer (score 11):

You can upgrade your Django using following command:

If you are using `pip3`:

```
sudo pip3 install django --upgrade
```

If `pip`:

```
sudo pip install django --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install Django --upgrade
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some information on how exactly this answers the question. This will make your question more understandable and useful to both the original asker and anyone in future. Thank you.