# AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError' python3.5

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My python ver=3.5

My django ver=1.9

I am new to django

I was trying to run a simple django app which gave me this error

`

```
d:\MAJORP~1\test\env\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py:85: 
DeprecationWarning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() instead
argspec = inspect.getargspec(receiver)
d:\MAJORP~1\test\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py:1108: Deprecation
Warning: inspect.getargspec() is deprecated, use inspect.signature() instead
params, varargs, varkw, defaults = getargspec(func)
AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'
```

`

please tell what is wrong here..

thanks in advance.

Comment: `html.parser` is deprecated from python 3.3, check this SO link for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827566/attributeerror-module-html-parser-has-no-attribute-htmlparseerror