# How to install downloaded django project in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to follow the instructions from this Django/Ajax tutorial: https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/. They say:

- Download the compressed pre-ajax Django Project from the repo https://github.com/realpython/django-form-fun/tree/master/part1
- Activate a virtualenv
- Install the requirements
- Sync the database
- Fire up the server

Here is what I am doing:

1. Create new virtualenv using `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 ajaxenv` inside `home/ajaxtutorial/` folder
2. Download the repo and unpack its `django-form-fun/part1/pre-ajax/talk_project/` folder in the `home/ajaxtutorial` folder.
3. Put the `requirements.txt` provided with the downloaded repo in `ajaxenv/bin`
4. Run `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside ajaxenv. At this point I can see that Django gets installed.

At this point the tutorial says to "sync the database". The only way I know how to do this is to use `python manage.py migrate`, but this throws an error. I guess this method requires starting the project or an app first, which is not a case here, since both the app and the project are downloaded, not created by me.

I don't know how to proceed from here. `python manage.py migrate` throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
    self._configure_logging()
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 72, in _configure_logging
    from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter, get_exception_reporter_filter
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.template import Template, Context, TemplateDoesNotExist
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from django.template.base import (ALLOWED_VARIABLE_CHARS, BLOCK_TAG_END,
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.utils.html import escape
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/html.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .html_parser import HTMLParser, HTMLParseError
  File "/home/bart/ajaxtutorial/ajaxenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/html_parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    HTMLParseError = _html_parser.HTMLParseError
AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'
```

Comment: You should google before asking questions :) Look for the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827566/attributeerror-module-html-parser-has-no-attribute-htmlparseerror)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827566/attributeerror-module-html-parser-has-no-attribute-htmlparseerror)